# Parsing date error

Tags: php, parsing, date

I have a very strange error which I dont understand. For some reason, certain dates are not properly parsed.

The code:

```
$day = strtotime($_GET['d']."-".$_GET['m']."-".$_GET['y']);
$dateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone("Europe/Prague");
$dateTime = new DateTime($day, $dateTimeZone);
$offset = ($dateTimeZone->getOffset($dateTime))/3600;
```

Now the really weird thing is.... 
if I pass in certain numbers, it works, but it doesnt with others...

For example a URL like this would work:

```
d=15&m=12&y=2014
```

But this:

```
d=12&m=12&y=2014
```

shows

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1418252400) at position 7 (4): Unexpected character' in

I have tried experimenting with it, also changing the format of the strtotime, but no luck and it just seems completely randomly working....

Comment: Why do you send date in separate parameters?

Comment: You don't need to use strtotime, you can pass date string directly into `DateTime` object. Error is probably due to incorrect order of day, month and year. It should be YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: What does `var_dump($day)` show when this happens?

Comment: @DavidKmenta If the problem is the order, why does it work for `15-12-2014` but not `12-12-2014`?

Comment: I tried this as well:
strtotime($_GET['y']."-".$_GET['m']."-".$_GET['d']);
and it produces the exact same error, no change

Comment: Why not use `mktime`, so you can pass each field as a separate argument?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it's a strtotime problem, but after some tests it's seems to be a problem of the DateTime object and that's strange... But I also found a solution. 1.) use `DateTime($_GET['y']."-".$_GET['m']."-".$_GET['d'])` as I said above or 2.) `(new DateTime())->setTimestamp(strtotime($_GET['y']."-".$_GET['m']."-".$_GET['d']))`

Comment: 11-11-2015 also doesn't work :) 10-10-2015 works, 9-9-2015 doesn't work. Very strange...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are sending timestamp as a parameter of DateTime object, you have to use `@` symbol as prefix. See this manual (UNIX timestamp): http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php

So, the correct way is:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('@' . $day, $dateTimeZone);
```

Or, what I prefer:

```
$dateTime = DateTime($_GET['y']."-".$_GET['m']."-".$_GET['d']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're sending it an invalid parameter.

> public DateTime::__construct ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )

That constructor expects a `A date/time string`, not a UNIX Timestamp as you are sending. Hence the exception. Remove the `strtotime` call around the date you are putting together.

Now you or someone else might ask why does it work for your other date then? No it doesn't work even then. Try your working date and see what DateTime date do you get

```
echo $dateTime->format("Y-m-d");
```

> 1600-04-01

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/307709)**

It doesn't (and shouldn't work) for either of your dates because of the strtotime call.

**[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)**